# Did fatima bath before her death so that none washed her body?

Tags: shiism, ahl-ul-bayt, funeral

I read in ibn al jawzis work talbis iblis that Shiism believes Fatima washed herself before her death so that it would suffice for funeral wash. (Page 177 English translation)

Is this narration correct, if its correct how does it take care of any discharges from anus and private part post death? Secondly how does she know shes going to die in few minutes or hours? Doesn't this contradict Shia view of imams only being inheritors of knowledge?

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely wrong. 
Shia believes After Fatima Al-Zahra (Salamullah Allayha) passed away, his husband Imam Ali (Allayhe Assalam) washed her body at night (gave her Ghusl) and buried her at night. In one narration Imam Ali (Allayhe Assalam) dug 40 graves for her so that no one discovers her grave and it remains unknown till now.

Comment: An evidence supporting your claim would be more helpful.

Comment: http://en.wikishia.net/view/Lady_Fatimah_al-Zahra%27_(a)#Martyrdom.2C_Funeral_and_Burial

Answer (score 0):

> Did fatima bath before her death so that none washed her body?

In a nutshell:

It has been narrated/proved based on diverse ways that: **Imam Ali (a.s.) has done Ghusl (غسل) for Hazrat-Fatimah (s.a.).**

Reference: https://www.yjc.ir/fa/news/7227662/

Answer (score 0):

Continuing the previous answers, I must say that according to the Shiite narrations , Imam Ali, the wife of Fatima( peace be upon her) bathed and shrouded her at night and buried her in the same midnight. So what you said is wrong.
But as for the continuation of the question you asked: How can anyone know the time of his death?
On the other hand, God says about this question: "And no one knows what he will gain tomorrow, and no one knows in what land he will die. "God is All-Knowing, All-Aware."

On the other hand, we read in many histories and narrations that the pure Imams (as) and even some of the saints other than the Imams knew of their deaths or stated their burial place.
Therefore, in the sum of these two issues and the apparent conflict that exists, we must say that awareness of some of these matters in the form of general knowledge - that is, through divine teaching - has no contradiction with assigning their detailed knowledge to the pure essence of God, and as we have said This conciseness is not inherent and independent, but has a transcendental and didactic aspect and is through divine teaching, to the extent that God wills and deems fit.
So the general rule in this case is not knowing the time of death, but exceptionally sometimes some people who have tried to purify the soul and cultivate the soul and are steadfast in the service of God. Like the late Sheikh Morteza Taleghani, Hakim Hidaji, the late Ayatollah Hojjat Kuh-e Kamraei, the father of Ayatollah Araki, Mirza Mahmoud Shaykh al-Islam, Ayatollah Shahaabadi, Ayatollah Seyyed Ahmad Khansari, etc. are aware of the divine teachings from the time of their death.

https://www.yjc.news/fa/news/7246318/

Answer (score 0):

Did Fatima take a bath before she died and no one washed her body?
No, this is not true, Hazrat Fatima (PBUH) commanded her husband Imam Ali (AS) to bathe her body. According to this will, Imam Ali (AS) bathed her body, and after bathing, they covered the body of Hazrat Fatima (AS) in seven pieces of cloth. علی According to his will, Imam Ali (AS) bathed and shrouded the body at night and buried it without the presence of the caliph and the general public. After burial, Imam Ali (AS) removed the traces of being a grave so that the grave would not be known.

Ref:https://fa.wikishia.net/view/%D8%AA%D8%B4%DB%8C%DB%8C%D8%B9_%D9%88_%D8%AA%D8%AF%D9%81%DB%8C%D9%86_%D8%AD%D8%B6%D8%B1%D8%AA_%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%B7%D9%85%D9%87(%D8%B3)#%D9%85%D8%AD%D9%84_%D8%AF%D9%81%D9%86